# Are the two ways of specifying the model equivalent when there are interactive terms?

Tags: interaction, model

Suppose we have continuous outcome variable $Y$, and we have a set of covariates $\mathbf{X}$  (assuming they are all continuous) and two binary variable $a$ and $t$. The goal is to estimate the effect of $a$ on $t$, but we suspect an interactive effect between $a$ and $t$, i.e., the effect of $a$ on $Y$ differs when $t=0$ vs $t=1$; and $t$ and $\mathbf{X}$.

Normally, we would specify the model as

$Y_i=\mathbf{X}_i\beta+\alpha a_i+\gamma t_i+\phi a_it_i + t\mathbf{X}_i\lambda+\epsilon_i$

What about specifying the model as

$Y_i = t_i(\mathbf{X}_i\beta_0 +\alpha_0a_i +\phi t_i)+ (1-t_i)(\mathbf{X}_i\beta_1 + \alpha_1a_i)+\epsilon_i?$

If they are not equivalent, where did I miss? ( I am triggered to ask this question is I was doing some simulation study and I am working on some models similar to the second one. The estimate of $\alpha_0$ turned out to be very close to the value I set up at the beginning. However, if I simulate data based on the first model and run the exact same analysis, the estimates are off from the initial value I set up for the simulation study).

Comment: The algebra works out, but the models are quite different: the first is linear in the parameters and the second is not.